# Ubuntu boot from internal HDD fails with "unable to find media containing live file system" message

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, system-installation

I have created a DVD containing Ubuntu 14.04 and have successfully run 14.04 from it. I have taken the option to install 14.04 as a dual boot with Windows XP.

The installation appeared to go smoothly and I have two extra partitions on my windows 'C' drive, /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7.

When I switch on the laptop I get the dual boot option. The Windows XP boot works ok (I'm using it now), but the Ubuntu 14.04 boot option runs so far, then terminates with the message:

(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

Any help will be gratefully accepted!

Roger

Comment: Boot from the DVD again and reinstall GRUB

Comment: Elder Geek you are a genius! It worked.  Now all I need to do is install the correct Broadcom drivers....

Many thanks

Comment: @LiveWireBT Consider it done.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the DVD again and reinstall grub. Instructions can be found [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

This has worked for me more times than I can count.